# Advanced GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects

I have a List of items with following structure:

1. Id
2. DateTime
3. Weight

How can group them by `Id` and **Date** of `Date` field (which is **DateTime**) and have the total weight of the group? I want something like this:

1. Id
2. Date
3. TotalWeight

Comment: Group them by what? `Id` and `Date`?

Comment: yes, I want it to be grouped by Id and Date (instead of DateTime)

Comment: Saeed's answer is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group them with both ID and Date you can do it like this:

```
var grp = from x in items
          group by new {x.Id, x.DateTime.Date};

var result = grp.Select(x=>new {item = x.Key, TotalWeight = x.Sum(y=>y.Weight)});
```

Comment: I want to group by `Date`, instead of `Datetime`

Comment: @RezaOwliaei, See my edit, but if this is for linq2EF, this wont work, if is so tell me to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from x in items
             group x by new { x.Id, x.DateTime.Date } into grouping
             select new 
             { 
                 id = grouping.Key.Id, 
                 Date = grouping.Key.Date, 
                 TotalWeight = grouping.Sum(y=>y.Weight)
             };
```